# How to cut off parts of a string, which every string in a collection has

Tags: c++, string, c++11, c++14, matching

My currently problem is the following:
I have a `std::vector` of full path names to files.
Now i want to cut off the common prefix of all string.

## Example

If I have these 3 strings in the vector:

```
/home/user/foo.txt
/home/user/bar.txt
/home/baz.txt
```

I would like to cut off `/home/` from every string in the vector.

## Question

Is there any method to achieve this in general?
I want an algorithm that drops the common prefix of all string.
I currently only have an idea which solves this problem in O(*n* *m*) with *n* strings and *m* is the longest string length, by just going through every string with every other string char by char.
Is there a faster or more elegant way solving this?

Comment: Given `/home/user/martin, /home/user/mike`, do you want the result to be `artin, ike` or `martin, mike`?  Your title says *string*, but your question says *path names*

Comment: I am sorry for the missunderstanding. Both results would be ok, if one of them could be implemented better than the other, i prefer this one

Comment: I cannot imagine a use case where both results would be OK

Comment: @Exagon can you check my answer? Is this what you want ?

Comment: @KostasRim no its not, I am sorry this is general enought

Comment: @Exagon the `find` function iterates through the string and returns the position(of the string) of the first character.

Comment: It's easy to see you can't be better in terms of big-O complexity.  Worst case: all strings are equal. **You have to check every single character of every single string to see that**. `n` strings, all of same length `m` => `m * n` steps. Still Martin Nyolt's solution should be faster in any practical case.

Comment: Will you profile different solutions? I think I can produce the fastest one (technically fastest, the O() will be still like O(mn), and more than O(mp) where p = length of common prefix, I don't think you can get under that one, as you have to verify the prefix is correct for every string).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done entirely with std:: algorithms.

synopsis:

1. sort the input range if not already sorted. The first and last paths in the sorted range
   will be the most dissimilar. Best case is O(N), worst case O(N + N.logN)
2. use `std::mismatch` to determine the larges common sequence between the
   two most dissimilar paths [insignificant]
3. run through each path erasing the first COUNT characters where COUNT is the number of characters in the longest common sequence. O (N)

Best case time complexity: O(2N), worst case O(2N + N.logN)  (can someone check that?)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string common_substring(const std::string& l, const std::string& r)
{
    return std::string(l.begin(),
                       std::mismatch(l.begin(), l.end(),
                                     r.begin(), r.end()).first);
}

std::string mutating_common_substring(std::vector<std::string>& range)
{
    if (range.empty())
        return std::string();
    else
    {
        if (not std::is_sorted(range.begin(), range.end()))
            std::sort(range.begin(), range.end());
        return common_substring(range.front(), range.back());
    }
}

std::vector<std::string> chop(std::vector<std::string> samples)
{
    auto str = mutating_common_substring(samples);
    for (auto& s : samples)
    {
        s.erase(s.begin(), std::next(s.begin(), str.size()));
    }
    return samples;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> samples = {
        "/home/user/foo.txt",
        "/home/user/bar.txt",
        "/home/baz.txt"
    };

    samples = chop(std::move(samples));

    for (auto& s : samples)
    {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }   
}
```

expected:

```
baz.txt
user/bar.txt
user/foo.txt
```

Here's an alternate `common_substring' which does not require a sort. time complexity is in theory O(N) but whether it's faster in practice you'd have to check:

```
std::string common_substring(const std::vector<std::string>& range)
{
    if (range.empty())
    {
        return {};
    }

    return std::accumulate(std::next(range.begin(), 1), range.end(), range.front(),
                           [](auto const& best, const auto& sample)
                           {
                               return common_substring(best, sample);
                           });
}
```

update:

Elegance aside, this is probably the *fastest* way since it avoids any memory allocations, performing all transformations in-place. For most architectures and sample sizes, this will matter more than any other performance consideration.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void reduce_to_common(std::string& best, const std::string& sample)
{
    best.erase(std::mismatch(best.begin(), best.end(),
                             sample.begin(), sample.end()).first,
               best.end());

}

void remove_common_prefix(std::vector<std::string>& range)
{
    if (range.size())
    {
        auto iter = range.begin();
        auto best = *iter;
        for ( ; ++iter != range.end() ; )
        {
            reduce_to_common(best, *iter);
        }

        auto prefix_length = best.size();

        for (auto& s : range)
        {
            s.erase(s.begin(), std::next(s.begin(), prefix_length));
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> samples = {
        "/home/user/foo.txt",
        "/home/user/bar.txt",
        "/home/baz.txt"
    };

    remove_common_prefix(samples);

    for (auto& s : samples)
    {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }   
}
```

Comment: This sorts the strings, and sorting is `O(n log n)`, which is slower than `O(n)` as the algorithm that OP has. (Ignoring `m` here, which is common to both.)

Comment: Granted, this might be more *elegant*, and the question was "Is there a faster *or* more elegant way solving this?". :)

Comment: @MartinNyolt if the strings are initially sorted, it's certainly faster. The sort is a fallback.

Comment: "Fallback" depends on the expected input. In the worst case, this is slower. If the input is usually in random order (e.g. file creation order), then the worst case is the default case, and your algorithm is certainly slower than the "naive" approach.

Comment: Thank you very much for this awesome answer

Comment: @Exagon you're more than welcome (and thankyou). In reality it's the standard library which is awesome. Not many people know how to use it well. Time spent learning its dark corners is time well-spent.

Comment: @Exagon further update at the end for ultimate performance over elegance.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to iterate over every string. You can only avoid iterating over the full length of strings needlessly by exploiting the fact, that the prefix can only shorten:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string common_prefix(const std::vector<std::string> &ss) {
    if (ss.empty())
        // no prefix
        return "";

    std::string prefix = ss[0];

    for (size_t i = 1; i < ss.size(); i++) {
        size_t c = 0; // index after which the string differ
        for (; c < prefix.length(); c++) {
            if (prefix[c] != ss[i][c]) {
                // strings differ from character c on
                break;
            }
        }

        if (c == 0)
            // no common prefix
            return "";

        // the prefix is only up to character c-1, so resize prefix
        prefix.resize(c);
    }

    return prefix;
}

void strip_common_prefix(std::vector<std::string> &ss) {
    std::string prefix = common_prefix(ss);
    if (prefix.empty())
        // no common prefix, nothing to do
        return;

    // drop the common part, which are always the first prefix.length() characters
    for (std::string &s: ss) {
        s = s.substr(prefix.length());
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> ss { "/home/user/foo.txt", "/home/user/bar.txt", "/home/baz.txt"};
    strip_common_prefix(ss);
    for (std::string &s: ss)
        std::cout << s << "\n";
}
```

Drawing from the hints of [Martin Bonner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39122085/1314743), you may implement a more efficient algorithm if you have more prior knowledge on your input.
In particular, if you know your input is sorted, it suffices to compare the first and last strings (see [Richard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39121913/1314743)).

Comment: this is assuming that the repeating part is always at the beginning of the strings

Comment: @slawekwin: I think that is what the OP is after.

Comment: Rather than `prefix = prefix.substr(0, c);`, use `prefix.resize(c)`.

Comment: `std::mismatch` can also be used to replace the inner loop.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You have to search every string in the list.  However you don't need to compare all the characters in every string.  The common prefix can only get shorter, so you only need to compare with "the common prefix so far".  I don't think this changes the big-O complexity - but it will make quite a difference to the actual speed.

Also, these look like file names.  Are they sorted (bearing in mind that many filesystems tend to return things in sorted order)?  If so, you only need to consider the first and last elements.  If they are *probably* pr *mostly* ordered, then consider the common prefix of the first and last, and then iterate through all the other strings shortening the prefix further as necessary.

Comment: I think most OS API calls won't return filenames in sorted order. `find / -maxdepth 1 | head` is a good example on my system. Only other user-friendly commands (like `ls` in unix) will sort. So it depends on the source of the file names. (And sorting strings will be slower than finding the common prefix on unsorted strings.)

Answer (score 1):

i - Find the file which has the least folder depth (i.e. baz.txt) - it's root path is home
ii - Then go through the other strings to see if they start with that root.
iii - If so then remove root from all the strings.

Answer (score 1):

Start with `std::size_t index=0;`.  Scan the list to see if characters at that index match (note: past the end does not match).  If it does, advance index and repeat.

When done, index will have the value of the length of the prefix.

At this point, I'd advise you to write or find a `string_view` type.  If you do, simply create a `string_view` for each of your strings `str` with start/end of `index, str.size()`.

Overall cost: `O(|prefix|*N+N)`, which is also the cost to confirm that your answer is correct.

If you don't want to write a `string_view`, simply call `str.erase(str.begin(), str.begin()+index)` on each `str` in your vector.

Overall cost is `O(|total string length|+N)`.  The prefix has to be visited in order to confirm it, then the tail of the string has to be rewritten.

Now the cost of the breadth-first is locality, as you are touching memory all over the place.  It will probably be more efficient in practice to do it in chunks, where you scan the first K strings up to length Q and find the common prefix, then chain that common prefix plus the next block.  This won't change the O-notation, but will improve locality of memory reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(vector<string>::iterator itr=V.begin(); itr!=V.end(); ++itr)
    itr->erase(0,6);
```

Comment: This is not general enough. The question says "*Like* if I have …". He is searching for an algorithm that automatically finds the "/home/" part. You should also explain your answer, not just provide code.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. This seems like the most straightforward answer to me. OP said *all* the strings in the collection shared the same prefix. It's quite reasonable to first find the length of that prefix, and then do what @Beta did.

Comment: @MartinNyolt: Saw your comment only after I posted. So the real question OP is asking is to first find the longest common prefix, and then chop that off?